# udev $kernel or %k substitution not expanding correctly

Tags: linux, bash, debian, udev

I'm having a lot of trouble with this. Thank you in advance for any help.

I'm trying to pass the `$kernel` or `%k` to a bash script on usb audio recorder input.  I have two issues and 1 challenge.

1. Neither `%k` or `$kernel` expands to "sdd" or "sdc", etc. instead i get a bunch of numbers.
2. udev runs the same script twice on connection, so the only thing I can think of is because the script runs once for the main kernel e.g. sdd and again for the partition sdd1. But that's only a guess.

The challenge I must contend with is that there are many of these devices physically plugged in roughly a few seconds apart from each other.  And they all match. I was using usbmount to auto mount the devices after they are inserted but even when using "sleep" in a bash script.  So.. I know I could mount them myself if I had the exact device kernel passed to the bash script.  However, since %k isn't expanding to sdd or whatever.. I can't run the mount command in the bash script. Below is the rule I've come up with.  Am I missing something?

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="07b4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0271", RUN+="/home/user/recorder.sh %k"
```

If I run `blkid` it shows me a list of all devices plugged in and their kernel path however there is no way for me to distinguish which one pertains to which udev rule is being run.

If no one has an idea what could be the issue, I could have someone manually run a script after all the devices are plugged, that runs the command `blkid`, and then parses out that information to start mounting them individually, but I'd prefer to figure out the first way.

Also, if the 2nd way is the way to go, could someone help me parse out to get just this information when running `blkid`.  fyi everything after the first colon can be arranged in different order as shown below, so if you're considering %2 to equal LABEL="WS_400S" all the time.. it won't.
example:

```
/dev/sdd1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="WS_400S" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sde1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" TYPE="vfat" LABEL="WS_400S"
/dev/sdf1: LABEL="WS_400S" SEC_TYPE="msdos" TYPE="vfat"
```

just interested in anything that matches the LABEL and outputs only the /dev/sd?? into a variable.

Comment: what action are you taking that would set a value for `%k` or `$kernel`? (what program are you running, or ???). Good luck.

Comment: I thought since udev rule gets activated on device input that udev knew what path the device was...and thus `%k` or $kernel would give that info.  Especially since if I use `%n` it correctly expands the correct kernel number of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem here is the rule match. When a single USB drive is plugged, a series of `udev` event are generated corresponding to all device nodes created (USB tree). The leaf is the partition (block device) and the top parent is a PCI bus.

  So rule matches two nodes which non of them was the leaf which has kernel name `sdxY` neither its direct parent node (disk) `sdx`.
- To see the whole tree and check when your rule is triggered, run:

  `udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/sdb1`

  ```
  Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
  walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
  found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
  A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
  and the attributes from one single parent device.

    looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1':
      KERNEL=="sdb1"
      SUBSYSTEM=="block"
      DRIVER==""
      ATTR{ro}=="0"
      ATTR{size}=="7892024"
      ATTR{stat}=="     174      606     1347      360        0        0        0        0        0      356      356"
      ATTR{partition}=="1"
      ATTR{start}=="63"
      ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
      ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
      ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb':
      KERNELS=="sdb"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="block"
      DRIVERS==""
      ATTRS{ro}=="0"
      ATTRS{size}=="7892087"
      ATTRS{stat}=="     189      655     1411     2208        0        0        0        0        0      600     2204"
      ATTRS{range}=="16"
      ATTRS{discard_alignment}=="0"
      ATTRS{events}=="media_change"
      ATTRS{ext_range}=="256"
      ATTRS{events_poll_msecs}=="2000"
      ATTRS{alignment_offset}=="0"
      ATTRS{inflight}=="       0        0"
      ATTRS{removable}=="1"
      ATTRS{capability}=="51"
      ATTRS{events_async}==""

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0':
      KERNELS=="7:0:0:0"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
      DRIVERS=="sd"
      ATTRS{rev}=="0.00"
      ATTRS{type}=="0"
      ATTRS{scsi_level}=="3"
      ATTRS{model}=="USB Flash Drive "
      ATTRS{state}=="running"
      ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
      ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0xe7"
      ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0xe7"
      ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
      ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
      ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
      ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
      ATTRS{max_sectors}=="240"
      ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x1"
      ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
      ATTRS{vendor}=="ADATA   "
      ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
      ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
      ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
      ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
      ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
      ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
      ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0':
      KERNELS=="target7:0:0"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
      DRIVERS==""

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host7':
      KERNELS=="host7"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
      DRIVERS==""

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0':
      KERNELS=="2-1.2:1.0"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
      DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
      ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
      ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
      ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="50"
      ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
      ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
      ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
      ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2':
      KERNELS=="2-1.2"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
      DRIVERS=="usb"
      ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
      ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
      ATTRS{devpath}=="1.2"
      ATTRS{idVendor}=="125f"
      ATTRS{speed}=="480"
      ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
      ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
      ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
      ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
      ATTRS{devnum}=="13"
      ATTRS{configuration}==""
      ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="98mA"
      ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
      ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
      ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
      ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
      ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
      ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
      ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
      ATTRS{serial}=="a01782d293d17d"
      ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
      ATTRS{urbnum}=="689"
      ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
      ATTRS{manufacturer}=="ADATA"
      ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
      ATTRS{idProduct}=="c96a"
      ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
      ATTRS{product}=="ADATA USB Flash Drive"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1':
      KERNELS=="2-1"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
      DRIVERS=="usb"
      ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
      ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
      ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
      ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
      ATTRS{speed}=="480"
      ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
      ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
      ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
      ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
      ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
      ATTRS{configuration}==""
      ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
      ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
      ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
      ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
      ATTRS{maxchild}=="8"
      ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
      ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
      ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
      ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
      ATTRS{urbnum}=="258"
      ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
      ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
      ATTRS{idProduct}=="0020"
      ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2':
      KERNELS=="usb2"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
      DRIVERS=="usb"
      ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
      ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
      ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
      ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
      ATTRS{speed}=="480"
      ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
      ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
      ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
      ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
      ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
      ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
      ATTRS{configuration}==""
      ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
      ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
      ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
      ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
      ATTRS{maxchild}=="3"
      ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
      ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
      ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
      ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
      ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
      ATTRS{urbnum}=="26"
      ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
      ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.0-49-generic ehci_hcd"
      ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
      ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
      ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
      ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0':
      KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.0"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
      DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
      ATTRS{irq}=="17"
      ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1028"
      ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
      ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
      ATTRS{companion}==""
      ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
      ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
      ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,0000000f"
      ATTRS{device}=="0x3b34"
      ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
      ATTRS{enable}=="1"
      ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
      ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
      ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
      ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x040a"
      ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
      ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
      KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
      SUBSYSTEMS==""
      DRIVERS==""
  ```

  1. `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` matches: `usb2`, `2-1`, `2-1.2`, `2-1.2:1.0`
  2. `ATTRS{idVendor}=="125f"` matches: `2-1.2`, `2-1.2:1.0`, `host7`, `target7:0:0`, `7:0:0:0`, `sdb`, `sdb1`
  3. `ATTRS{idProduct}=="c96a"` matches: `2-1.2`, `2-1.2:1.0`, `host7`, `target7:0:0`, `7:0:0:0`, `sdb`, `sdb1` (same as `ATTRS{idVendor}=="07b4"`)

  For a rule to be triggered, all conditions must match. So only `2-1.2` & `2-1.2:1.0` nodes will trigger this rule.
- A way to confirm write new rules as:

  ```
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="125f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c96a", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo `date` %k %p >> /tmp/usb-key-nodes.log' "
  ```

  After reloading rules and replug the key:

  `tail /tmp/usb-key-nodes.log`

  ```
  Mon Jul 6 17:08:38 CET 2015 1-2 /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
  Mon Jul 6 17:08:38 CET 2015 1-2:1.0 /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
  ```